# versions of netcat

Tags: shell, networking, command-line, netcat

I've tried the two main versions of netcat : GNU and BSD. (mine is BSD Version).

On GNU version, the command $ nc -l -p 12345 works fine
but with BSD, option -l (listen) can't be used in conjonction with -p (local port).

I don't understand why there is a such difference between these two versions ? 
In the BSD version, when I use option -p, it calls automatically -l (listen) ?

thanks ;-)

Ps: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netcat-openbsd/+bug/590925/comments/3
-p is different between the two. The OpenBSD version uses it to set a
source port for remote connections, while the traditional nc uses it to
specify the local port on which it will listen when in listen mode.

Comment: In the BSD version, `-l` takes the port to listen on, so `-p` is not needed at all. I'm not sure what `-p` does without `-l`. I don't know why there's a difference.

Comment: Try ncat (in the nmap distro).

Comment: Try socat, completely different syntax, but way more capabilities than the good old netcat's.

Comment: @icktoofay if you move you're comment to answers i'll upvote then vote to close ... just tag me in the post so i see it

Comment: The Ubuntu packages are `netcat-traditional` for GNU, and `netcat-openbsd` and `netcat` for BSD.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/346869/what-are-the-diffrences-between-netcat-traditional-and-netcat-openbsd

Answer (score 5):

In the BSD version, -l takes the port to listen on, so -p is not needed at all. I'm not sure what -p does without -l. I don't know why there's a difference. – icktoofay <--credit for the solution goes to that guy...but I don't think he has an account on SU, just SO.